# Trace norm of a matrix product

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, non-convex-optimization

Is there a way to write the trace norm of the product of two matrices function of the separated trace norm of those two matrices. Or maybe a good approximation for it function of the same matrices. I want this because i am trying to optimize an objective function that has the trace of the product of two matrices as a regulizer. Having this approximation, this would allow me to use the proximal gradient method as an optimization method to solve the problem.

$$\min_A f(A) +\|AX\|$$

where $\|.\|$ is the trace norm. I want to minimize it with respect to $A$. $f$ is differentiable and convex.

Comment: for the trace norm you mean $\|M\|=\sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(M^TM)}$?

Comment: Yes Precisely, also called the nuclear norm

Comment: So the proximal operator of the nuclear norm is the soft thresholding of the SVD (see http://lcsl.mit.edu/data/silviavilla/Teaching_files/20141008_mit.pdf) so you could use a Chambolle-Pock type approach (https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00490826/document) I think or simply alternate between gradient descent and proximal (see for example http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-S15/scribes/08-prox-grad-scribed.pdf)

Comment: Thank you @tibL for the notation correction and the useful answer. However i can't use those methods because my trace norm is a linear transformation of the term they are using as a regulizer. So the problem is at some point i will have to compute the proximal operator with respect to the norm who takes A as entry and gives  A-->\|AX\| as a norm

Comment: isn't that precisely the case suggested in Chambolle and Pock? They optimise $F(Kx) + G(x)$ with $K$ a linear operator. It may be that you can apply exactly the same method but it's probably worth following their argument in your case?